# Testing Controller Action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Im having issues testing the controller action for my POST response via the FRESHDESK API

```
def post_inquiry
  @cert_inquiry = Form.new(params[:cert_inquiry])
  if @cert_inquiry.valid?
    @cert_inquiry.post_tickets(subject_title)
    flash[:success] = 'Message sent! Thank you for contacting us.'
    redirect_to '/flat-roof-mounting/resources'
  else
    flash[:alert] = 'Please fill in the required fields'
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

heres my spec

```
let!(:cert_params) do
  {
    "subject"=>"test",
    "email"=>"test@test.com",
    "custom_field"=>{"cert_letter_state_28445"=>"CA"},
    "description"=>"test"
  }
end

describe 'POST #post_inquiry' do
  def do_post
    post :post_inquiry, cert_inquiry: cert_params
  end

  before{ expect(Form).to receive(:new).with(cert_params) }

  it do
    do_post
    expect(response).to redirect_to '/flat-roof-mounting/resources'
  end
 end
```

heres my failures (amongst the many others in life)

```
 Failure/Error: post :post_inquiry, cert_inquiry: cert_params
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `valid?' for nil:NilClass
```

its calling through to the Freshdesk API.....do I have to stub out the api call somehow?  If so how?  i Have like api keys urls and all that good stuff but not sure what I'm suppose to do with it

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the following:

`before { expect(Form).to receive(:new).with(cert_params) }`

to:

`before { expect(Form).to receive(:new).with(cert_params).and_call_original }`

and see if it works.

Comment: first of all thank you for your response.....secondly when I added the .and_call_original i get a      NoMethodError:
       undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass